# LMest for cluster membership over time

Tags: time-series, classification, unsupervised-learning, hidden-markov-model

I have a dataset of 18 continuous variables measured over 3 time points for 90 patients. I hypothesise that there are clusters of patients with similar characteristics and that cluster membership may change with time (a drug was given at t = 0).

I have identified Latent Transition Analysis/Generalized Markov Models as a potential approach and since I aim to implement the analysis in R, I've started with the package `LMest`.

```
fmLatent <- lmestFormula(data = mets_complete, response = response_vars,
                        LatentInitial = c("age", "diagnosis"), LatentTransition = c("age", "diagnosis"))
basic_mod_3 <- lmestCont(responsesFormula = fmLatent$responsesFormula, 
                         latentFormula = fmLatent$latentFormula, 
                         index = c("id", "Time_weeks"),
                         data = mets_complete, k =1:7,
                         start = 1, modBasic = 2)
```

The output of `summary(basic_mod_3)` contains initial probabilities and transition probabilities, but no group membership.

I have tried running `lmestDecoding` on a simpler model - based on the vignette, I thought this would estimate group membership. However, I noticed that the transition probabilities do not match with what I assumed was the group membership, so I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Isn't classification part of the algorithm? Should I be considering alternative approaches to my problem?

Comment: I'd have thought ````lmestDecoding```` should do this. Maybe "what you assumed was the group membership" was wrong? Where is your assumption from and how sure are you, on what basis?

Comment: The result from `lmestDecoding` is a list with Ul and Ug. According to the help file, they are the matrices of local and global decoded states corresponding to each row of Y, respectively. Since I have 3 time points and there are three columns, I am assuming each column represents the state at a given time point for that individual. In Ul, each individual goes form 1 > 2 > 3. While in Ug, all individuals are in 2 for all time points.